# Align tfoot to bottom while generating a PDF file (flying-saucer/itext)

Tags: java, pdf, itext, footer, flying-saucer

I'm using flying-saucer/itext to generate PDF files based on HTML and I ran into the problem of adding a header and a footer to the PDF files. I ended up doing an HTML table with a theader and a tfooter, something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Header stuff
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Footer stuff
        </th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Content
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Along with the css rule "table { -fs-table-paginate: paginate; }" the header and footer paginate properly. However, I cannot make the footer stick to the bottom of the page:

[image]

If the content of the table fill the page, then the footer is pushed to the bottom:

[image]

Is there a way to push the footer to the bottom even if the tbody isn't full??

Thanks,
Julián

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CSS 3 Paged media](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) to add header and footer to a PDF.
This will solve your problem (display footer at the bottom of the page), but also give you a lot of nice options (page numbers, specific header for first page...)

Here is the basic template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
     #header { position: running(header); }
     #footer { position: running(footer); }

     @page {
       @top-center    { content: element(header); }
       @bottom-center { content: element(footer); }
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='header'>Header stuff</div>
    <div id='footer'>Footer stuff</div>

    <table>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  Content
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```